# Matching pattern 2 data frames r

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have two data frames that contains strings that are slightly different let's say:

```
Name              Size
Company.1 Inc.    234
Company.2 LLC     164
Company.3 INC     231
```

On the other hand, my second data frame is:

```
Name              State
Company.1 INC     MA
Company.2         NY
Company.3 inc.    CA
```

Do you know a tool that could for example match the first 6 characters and merge into a new table the result (or at least shows me the option if there is a multiple match)?

I tried grep or sapply but it is not working because I need to compare all name values of the first data frame to all the name value of the second one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the expected outcome for your example?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like all you need here is to use `match` in order to match the first 9 letters in both files, something like (I'm assuming here `df1` is your first data set and `df2` is the second respectively)

```
indx <- match(substr(df1$Name, 1, 9), substr(df2$Name, 1, 9))
df1["State"] <- df2$State[indx]
df1
#             Name Size State
# 1 Company.1 Inc.  234    MA
# 2  Company.2 LLC  164    NY
# 3  Company.3 INC  231    CA
```

Or using some fast join using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1)[, Name := substr(Name, 1, 9)], Name)
setDT(df2)[, Name := substr(Name, 1, 9)]
df1[df2]
#         Name Size State
# 1: Company.1  234    MA
# 2: Company.2  164    NY
# 3: Company.3  231    CA
```